# Hibernate left join fetch to soft-deleted entity mapped with @ManyToMany association generates invalid query?

Tags: java, hibernate

I don't know if this is a problem with Hiberante or if I'm doing something wrong.

I tried to make this example as simple as possible.

My entities:

Book.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="books")
@SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE books set is_deleted = true where id = ?")
@Where(clause="is_deleted = false")
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column (name="is_deleted")
    private boolean deleted;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name="books_authors",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name="id_books")
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name="id_authors")
            }
    )
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

    //getters/setters
}
```

Author.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="autors")
@SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE autors set is_deleted = true where id = ?")
@Where(clause="is_deleted = false")
public class Author implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column (name="is_deleted")
    private boolean deleted;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

    //getters/setters
}
```

underlying tables:

```
create table autors (
    id int8 not null,
    is_deleted boolean,
    name varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
); 
   
create table books (
    id int8 not null,
    is_deleted boolean,
    title varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
); 
   
create table books_authors (
    id_books int8 not null,
    id_authors int8 not null,
    primary key (id_books, id_authors)
);
alter table if exists books_authors add constraint FK9xru8ocoxufr5eva6atfyfjxh foreign key (id_authors) references autors;
alter table if exists books_authors add constraint FKx5d5025t9ct5kcbwwxm6tipo foreign key (id_books) references books;
```

Data:

```
select * from books;
```

| id | is_deleted | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | false | TITLE_1 |
| 2 | false | TITLE_2 |

```
select * from authors;
```

| id | is_deleted | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | false | not deleted |
| 2 | true | DELETED! |

```
select * from books b
join books_authors ba on b.id = ba.id_books 
join autors a on a.id = ba.id_authors;
```

| id | is_deleted | title | id_books | id_authors | id | is_deleted | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | false | TITLE_1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | false | not deleted |
| 2 | false | TITLE_2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | true | DELETED! |

JPQL:

```
public Optional<Book> getBookWithSoftDeletedAuthor(long bookId) {
    List<Book> myBooks = em.createQuery(
            "select b from " +
            "Book b " +
            "left join fetch b.authors a " +
            "where b.id = :bookId", Book.class)
            .setParameter("bookId", bookId)
            .getResultList();
    return myBooks.size() > 0 ? Optional.of(myBooks.get(0)) : Optional.empty();
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="WildflyUnit">
        <description> Persistence unit for Wildfly </description>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/WildflyDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"/> 
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

datasource from Wildfly's standalone.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/WildflyDataSource" pool-name="WildflyDataSource" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/TestDB</connection-url>
    <driver>postgresql</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>wildfly_user</user-name>
        <password>********</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

Hibernate generates sql statement like this:

```
select
    book0_.id as id1_1_0_,
    author2_.id as id1_0_1_,
    book0_.is_deleted as is_delet2_1_0_,
    book0_.title as title3_1_0_,
    author2_.is_deleted as is_delet2_0_1_,
    author2_.name as name3_0_1_,
    authors1_.id_books as id_books1_2_0__,
    authors1_.id_authors as id_autho2_2_0__ -- this column is not null even if the author is soft-deleted
from
    books book0_ 
left outer join
    books_authors authors1_ 
        on book0_.id=authors1_.id_books 
left outer join
    authors author2_ 
        on authors1_.id_authors=author2_.id 
        and (
            author2_.is_deleted = false
        ) 
where
    (
        book0_.is_deleted = false
    ) 
    and book0_.id=2
```

imho Hibernate should generate this query like this:

```
 select
    book0_.id as id1_1_0_,
    author2_.id as id1_0_1_,
    book0_.is_deleted as is_delet2_1_0_,
    book0_.title as title3_1_0_,
    author2_.is_deleted as is_delet2_0_1_,
    author2_.name as name3_0_1_,
    book0_.id as id_books1_2_0__,
    author2_.id as id_autho2_2_0__ 
from
    books book0_ 
left outer join
    books_authors authors1_ 
        on book0_.id=authors1_.id_books 
left outer join
    authors author2_ 
        on authors1_.id_authors=author2_.id 
        and (
            author2_.is_deleted = false
        ) 
where
    (
        book0_.is_deleted = false
    ) 
    and book0_.id=2
```

the id_autho2_2_0__ column should come from author2_ (authors table), not from authors1_ (books_authors table). Since the value of the authors1_.id_authors column is not null, hibernate tries to fetch a soft deleted entity from the authors table.

I use Hibernate 5.4.27.Final

Comment: Actually, I think Hibernate should generate a table group join for this instead. I assume you have some configuration properties set as well? Please post them.

Comment: I added presistence.xml and datasource from wildfly's standalone.xml configuration file.

Comment: Hmm ok, I think the issue is that the table group join is not added because the additional condition is contributed through the `@Where` annotation rather than through a `ON` or `WITH` clause. Please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: thanks, Issue created (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14437) ;)

Comment: @mil any workaround that you are currently using? Currently, I am implementing the entity of mapping Table as well and soft deleting the mapping table as well. Works well for new associations but refactoring old associations is painful.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov what is table group join? Can you point me to some resource about that. Thanks.

Comment: This is the join that is semantically correct `from books book0_ left outer join (books_authors authors1_ inner join authors author2_ on authors1_.id_authors=author2_.id) on book0_.id=authors1_.id_books and (author2_.is_deleted = false)`

Comment: Thanks @ChristianBeikov I get it. Unfortunately we are using Entity Graph a lot and refactoring will be tremendous effort. I am also surprised that this is the only place I see this issue being discussed. I wonder if old version of Hibernate have this issue.

Comment: Yes, also older versions of Hibernate have this issue. This was fixed for certain other association joins but apparently not for this kind of association join. A possible workaround is to avoid join fetching and instead use custom queries with DTOs. I bet you'd love what Blaze-Persistence Entity Views has to offer: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage